# Gridview header and footer transparncy view

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm developing grid view program its working fine. But I used top and bottom view inside gridview if scroll to top means the top view hide the gridview items. I need to overlaps the view i have transparency images in top view. But its not working for me. If any one have any idea share with me..

Thanks in advance